# QMainWindow doesn’t resize when child widget gets resized

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following problem.I have a QmainWindow which sets main layout and a widget added to that Layout.
When I resize the widget the QmainWindows remains the same size.

Here is the setup:
In the QmainWindow on init:

```
this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);

m_mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
m_mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

m_centralWidget = new QWidget();

m_centralWidget->setLayout(m_mainLayout);
setCentralWidget(m_centralWidget);

this->setMinimumSize(800,600);

m_mainLayout->addWidget(m_GLWidget);
```

Then,at some point m_GLWidget signals it needs to be resized.QmainWindow catches the signal and

reized the m_GLWidget:

```
 void MainWindow::ResizeViewportSlot(int w,int h){

  m_GLWidget->setFixedSize(w,h);

  m_GLWidget->updateGeometry();

  this->updateGeometry();


}
```

Comment: Cause you set the minimum size on `QMainWindow`?

Comment: So how do I set some default size to the main window without using setMinimumSize() ,which I already see is the cause of the problem?

Comment: You may use [`resize(800, 600)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop) in the constructor instead of `setMinimumSize` which creates limits.

Comment: Great!!!!!That's what I was after!You could put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `resize(800, 600)` in the constructor instead of `setMinimumSize` which creates limits.

By the way, although it's a common function, [`resize`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop) is inherited from [`QWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop) and many people (me included) can't find it in the document page of [`QMainWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html).

I think you are just one of the victims.

#### [Edit]

Thanks to lpapp's comment:

"Usually one can click on the [**`List of all members, including inherited members`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow-members.html)  link to get to all the members of a class."

Comment: Usually one can click on the `List of all members, including inherited members` link to get to all the members of a class. It refers to the following url in this particular case: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmainwindow-members.html

Comment: @lpapp That's...that's `Qt5` document, dude.

Comment: It has been the same mechanism at least since Qt 3. Please refer to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow-members.html for Qt 4.